# Data structures - asymptotic analysis (C++)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Does anyone know where I can find nicely organized in one placed (maybe a table, but doesn't have to) an asymptotic analysis of basic data structures. I'd like to refresh my understanding of data structures and also search and sorting algorithms.
So I'm looking for best, avg. and worst case scenarios.

It wouldn't hurt if it included STL.

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful resources you can use:

> [Bigochecksheet](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/)

This includes tables that you asked for. Great way to refresh you knowledge.

> What you can do it print this sheet and paste it somewhere you can see them every day continuously.